# can we fire up one button from another

Tags: android, android-button, buttonclick

Is there a way that we can fire up a button from another button in Android. Let's say when I click `button1` to call the `onClick()` function of `button2`?

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/button2" 
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `onClick()` of your first button, you can do

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    btn2.performClick();
}
```

the `performClick()` method will fire `btn2`'s `onClick()`

[Docs for performClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick())